# adding text blocks to div and setting width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having canvas

```
<div id="app-container">
    <div id="canvas-container">
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in css I have

```
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app-container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm trying to add text block to canvas

```
$container= $("#canvas");
var $view = $("#template-textview").tmpl();
$("<div class=\"text-field\">" + me.text + "</div>").appendTo($view);
$view.appendTo($container);
```

after that text takes all width. How can I tell it to take only width, required by text?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a block element ( `div` ) it naturally expands to 100% of the parent width.

To fix that try to make it `inline-block` :

```
div.text-field { display: inline-block }
```

Answer (score 1):

With this ?

```
#canvas {
    width: auto;
}
```